Why doesn't sodium form organometallic compounds with alkyl halides?
Both magnesium as well as lithium, on reaction with an alkyl halide (say chloroethane), form an organometallic compound. However, sodium and potassium do not exhibit such a reaction. Instead of sending electron to the halogen and forming a carbanion (as in case of magnesium and lithium), sodium and potassium show Wurtz reaction when reacted with an alkyl halide in dry ether.
Does sodium form an organometallic compound on reaction with alkyl halide (even as a minor product)? If not, what's the reason?

Sodium can indeed react with an alkyl halide to form an organometallic compound. But it does not last. In the Wurtz reaction, the organosodium compound
commonly  couples with more of the alkyl halide to form a dimerized alkane:
$\ce{R — X + 2Na -> R — Na + NaCl}$
$\ce{R — Na + R — X -> R — R + NaCl}$
This coupling destroys the nucleophilic function that is typically desired when an organometallic compound is formed from an alkyl halide in this way.
Lithium and magnesium in place of sodium are not immune to this coupling, but with their smaller ionic and atomic radii they produce better covalent overlap with carbon and thus form strong enough metal-carbon bonds to enable isolation of the polar organometallic compound before it would undergo the coupling reaction.
In addition, when the organometallic compound is applied to a substrate such as a Grignard reagent reacting with a ketone, the partially ionic lithium or magnesium has some electrophilic character which works hand-in-hand with the nucleophilic organic part of the molecule. In the case of a Grignard reagent plus a ketone, the electrophilic magnesium attacks the oxygen end of the carbonyl group as the nucleophilic carbon from the Grignard reagent goes to work on the ketone's carbonyl carbon. Heavier metals from Groups 1 and 2, with larger and more diffuse ions, make poorer electrophilic complements.

Will the organometallic compound last if aryl halide was used?

See the Wurtz-Fittig reaction.

Tl;DR: Both reaction follows different reaction mechanism, hence the end products are different.
Long Answer:
Sodium reacting with alkyl halide, also called Wurtz reaction proceeds by an initial metal–halogen exchange described with the following idealized stoichiometry:
$\ce{R−X + 2Na -> R-Na + NaX}$
This step may involve the intermediacy of radical species $\ce{R·}$ and is susceptible to diverse reactions. The organometallic intermediate ($\ce{RNa}$) next reacts with the alkyl halide ($\ce{RX}$) forming a new carbon–carbon covalent bond.
$\ce{RNa + RX → R−R + NaX}$
The process resembles an SN2 reaction, but the mechanism is probably complex.
The mechanism is described in the Wikipedia article

The reaction between magnesium and alkyl halide also involves radical intermediates but there is one major difference - it does not involve a radical chain mechanism. It is a non-chain radical reaction. The reaction is conducted by adding the organic halide to a suspension of magnesium in an ethereal solvent, which provides ligands required to stabilize the organomagnesium compound. Empirical evidence suggests that the reaction takes place on the surface of the metal.
Magnesium wants to get rid of these two electrons to get full octet but in this reaction, both these electrons will not be released over immediately. Only one electron will be handed to halide, and other will remain on magnesium. This is the rate-determining step. The next step is the homolytic cleavage of the negatively charged alkyl halide radical. One electron of this bond will fill the halide octet and give it a negative charge. An alkyl radical is also formed. Then, this alkyl radical and positively charged magnesium radical will connect their lone electrons and form a bond with a positive charge on magnesium. In the end, this cation and halide anion give the Grignard reagent.

(Above Mechanism and Image Source)
More on that here: https://research.cm.utexas.edu/nbauld/grignard.htm

This answer does not explain why sodium and magnesium have different behavior. Sure, the different reactions have different mechanisms, but the main question is why sodium & potassium do one and magnesium & lithium do the other.
